# Ant: How ant finds property setter method for a property

Tags: java, ant

I am referring sample here: https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-tasks-filesets-properties.html

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;

public class Find extends Task {

    private String property;
    private String value;
    private String print;

    public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    // setter for value and print

    public void execute() {
        if (print != null) {
            String propValue = getProject().getProperty(print);
            log(propValue);
        } else {
            if (property == null) throw new BuildException("property not set");
            if (value    == null) throw new BuildException("value not set");
            getProject().setNewProperty(property, value);
        }
    }
}
```

The sample extends an Ant task to build a custom task. The ant task script given

```
   <find property="test" value="test-value"/>
   <find print="test"/>
```

The script is setting values for couple of properties "property" and "print". My question is how does Ant determines that it has to call "setProperty" method to set the value for "property" attribute? Basically how Ant determines which method from the class to call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Writing Your Own Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html):

> For each attribute, write a setter method. The setter method must be a public void method that takes a single argument. **The name of the method must begin with set, followed by the attribute name**, with the first character of the name in uppercase, and the rest in lowercase*. That is, to support an attribute named file you create a method setFile.

And from [The Life-cycle of a Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html):

> 7. ...
> 8. All attributes of this task get set via their corresponding setXXX methods, at runtime.
> 9. ...

Comment: Thank you so much. I was thinking the same but wanted an expert advice